# Probability of Event from a table

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have the following table:

[image: SPSS output]

From here I want to answer the following question:

P(CHILD CAN RECOG BEG SOUNDS OF WORDS – YES | CHILD RECOGNIZES LETTERS  - Most of them). From my understanding of this I am saying 81.1%, am I reading this correctly?

Child Can Recog (Recognize) Beg (Begining) Sounds of Words. So what I am trying to find from the data, is: The Probability that a Child can recognize beginning sounds of words (1 - Yes) given that the child recognizes most of the letters.

So what I did was go to the Row 1-Yes, then the row in that area labeled % within PE2 - Child recognizes letters and then over to column 2 called 2 Most of Them and picked the 81.1%

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing the following:

```
                      RECOG LETTER - MOST | RECOG LETTER OTHER | TOTAL
RECOGNIZE WORD YES          361           |       858          | 1219
RECOGNIZE WORD NO           84            |       232          | 316
TOTAL                       445           |       1090         | 1535

361/1535 = 0.24, 858/1535 = 0.56, 84/1535 = 0.05, 232/1535 = 0.15
```

Which gave me the following:

```
                       RECOG LETTER - MOST | RECOG LETTER OTHER | TOTAL
RECOGNIZE WORD YES           0.24          |       0.56         | 0.8
RECOGNIZE WORD NO            0.05          |       0.15         | 0.2
TOTAL                        0.29          |       0.71         | 1

P(RECOG LETTER - MOST) = 0.29

P(RECOGNIZE WORD YES) = 0.8

P(RECOG LETTER MOST AND RECOG WORD YES) = 0.24

P(RECOG LETTER MOST OR RECOG WORD YES) = 0.24 + 0.05 + 0.56 = 0.85
```

So then I did the following:

```
P(RECOG WORD YES | RECOG LETTER MOST)
= P(WORD YES AND MOST) / P(WORD YES)
= 0.24 / 0.8
= 0.3
```

Comment: Can you spell these out, & say more about your situation & your data?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question.